# css2pdf xepOnline Cloudformatter - Hide elements in html but display in PDF

Tags: html, pdf-generation, css-to-pdf

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.PrintMedia

There is an option in this cloudformatter called 'noprint' which can be applied to elements which display on the html page but aren't added to the PDF. What I want is the opposite. I want elements not to appear on the html page but appear in the PDF.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Set the div to display:none and then in your @media print CSS set it to display:block. This is in effect the opposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my comment above, I created a simple fiddle for you.

There is a block with class .printme which is set normally to display:none. Then in your @media print CSS rules you set that block to display:block. I left the sample from @cloudformatter the same so you can see that it hides one paragraph in the PDF and displays the other.

While the input HTML would look like this:

[image]

As you can see in the fiddle in the raw HTML, one block displayed and the other is not because of this CSS:

```
.printme { display:none;}
@media print {
  .noprint {display:none;}
  .printme {display:block;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4gnomkn/1/

The result PDF shows one block hidden and your hidden block revealed. Of course that could be a div as large as you wish:

[image]